# How do I populate my empty working tree from the repository in git?

Tags: git, reset

I must be missing something, because I've read all the doc for reset, revert, etc., but I can't work out how to get the contents of my index into the working tree. (I copied the `.git` folder from elsewhere and just want to do a 'get latest').

Comment: It sounds like you *might* be mistaken about what the index is.

Comment: The git command that does exactly what you describe is `git checkout-index`, but I'm afraid that's not really what you're looking for.

Comment: In the described case, it is `git checkout -f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git commit -m'for now'
git checkout -f
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

- The first step will store the index changes in the repository DAG.
- The `checkout` step is necessary here because your repository doesn't have a working tree (i.e. it consists of nothing but the .git/ directory), and so the checkout will arrange for the working tree to reflect `HEAD`.
- The last step points the `HEAD` reference to its parent, thus effectively discarding the last commit. The commit is still in the DAG, pointed at by the reflog should you ever care to look at it, but its not part of your branch's timeline anymore. This step is a **soft** reset, which means that Git places back the changes of that last commit in the index, and it doesn't change the working tree from how it looked when `HEAD` pointed at that last commit we committed. The commit is not part of your history but the changes are still there in the working tree *and* in the stage.

Comment: OK, so given the situation I'm in (just the .git folder with nothing else), that would be commit/checkout/soft reset? I can see that working. Can I/you edit your answer to that?

Comment: Yep. Done. I also added some extra details about each step.

Comment: I don't know if I was mistaken as @MatrixFrog and @Autocracy seem to think, but you apparently understood what I wanted, and the green tick is yours, sir :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `git clone /path/to/myproject.git` ?

Or `git clone /path/to/my/copied/.git`

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -f HEAD
```

That will cause all of the files to be forcefully checked out, overwriting what git thinks is currently a deletion. HEAD can also be any reference (branch, commit id, etc).